# Maven Sonar plugin issue

Tags: maven, plugins, sonarqube

I am getting below error on my build :

The POM for org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:jar:3.7.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0: Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:jar:3.7.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

I have already tried [Why sonar-maven-plugin-3.0.1.jar cannot be found when executing sonar:sonar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35286882/why-sonar-maven-plugin-3-0-1-jar-cannot-be-found-when-executing-sonarsonar) solution , didn't workout

Comment: Try adding `<plugin><groupid>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupid><artifactid>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactid<version><3.7.0</version></plugin>` to the `plugins` section of your pom.xml (or update it accordingly) or run `mvn org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0:sonar` instead.

Comment: thanks @dan1st, however i am getting below error now:

Comment: ERROR] Plugin org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:jar:3.7.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -

Comment: My fault. It is `3.7.0.1746` instead of `3.7.0`.

Comment: @dan1st still getting same error

Comment: Is the new version shown in the error?

Comment: @dan1st this is the error :

Comment: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar (default-cli) on project parking: Unable to read plugin manifest from jar : /var/lib/jenkins/.sonar/cache/a9a8208ab5317e9ddec169b04203f5ea/sonar-kotlin-plugin.jar: invalid LOC header (bad signature) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]

Comment: @dan1st yes it is

Comment: This seems like a completely different error...

Comment: @dan1st oh sorry so now I am getting this error after implementing solution

Comment: Try executing `mvn clean install -U` and then run the command agsin with `-U`.